# Alamofire 4 progress on request

Tags: json, swift, request, alamofire, progress

I must request on a big JSON file (more than 6Mo).

I migrate from Alamofire 3 to 4.
With Alamofire 4 I can't detect progress on request operation.
I try to use download with progressDownload but value for progress.totalUnitCount is always on -1 and in responseJSON I've got a failure 'responseSerializationFailed'.

Here is my code testing :

```
// It's work but I can't have progress handler
Alamofire.request(path)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result.value)
    }
```

And with this :

```
Alamofire.download(pathRequete)
   .downloadProgress { progress in
        // OK but -1 for progress.totalUnitCount
        print(progress.fractionCompleted, progress.completedUnitCount, progress.totalUnitCount)
   }
   .responseJSON { response in
        // Failure here 'responseSerializationFailed'
        print(response.result.value)
   }
```

Someone have a solution ?

Comment: If there's no content-length being returned for that image URL, then progress reporting won't work. iOS defaults to -1 when it doesn't know what the total image size will be.
(cf : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1904)

Comment: Thanks for your response.